# exception gets handled by the outermost try/catch. windows services

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, exception, windows-services

Function that throws the `ThirdPartyException` (I don't know how does their code work) exception:

```
private void RequestDocuments(/* arguments... */) {
    while(true) {
        var revision = lastRevision;
        var fetchedDocuments = 0;

        try {
            foreach(var document in connection.QueryDocuments(revision)) {
                if(fetchedDocuments > fetchQuota) return;

                container.Add(document);
                ++fetchedDocuments;

                Logger.Log.InfoFormat("added document (revision: {0}) into inner container", document.Revision);
            }

            Logger.Log.Info("Done importing documents into the inner container");
            return;
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            if(ex is ThirdPartyException) {
                // handle this in a certain way!
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this function is called inside a worker thread like this:

```
private void ImportDocuments() {
    while(!this.finishedEvent.WaitOne(0, false)) {
        try {
            var documents = new List<GohubDocument>();
            RequestDocuments(remoteServerConnection, documents, lastRevision, 100);
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            // here is where it really gets handled!!!?
        }
    }
}
```

the exception is handled only in the outermost (which is inside the `ImportDocuments` method) `try/catch`.

Why is that?

Comment: Use Edit + Advanced + Format Document.  Fairly good odds you'll now see the bug in your code.

Comment: Then at least use it to improve the formatting of your code snippet.  The poor indenting gives *way* too many bad leads.

Comment: What Exception type you get in the second catch? The "handle this in a certain way!" can be throwing.

Comment: Now you've posted code that cannot compile.  The catch statement is outside the try block and the *continue* statement is outside the while() loop.  Clearly something is very borken in your real code and you're doing a poor job of documenting it.  Surely the underlying reason for this problem.

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you for your corrections on code formatting. Altough you were right about it you produced nothing except mocking me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that's a LINQ API which exposes `IQueryable` you don't get an error due to the deferred execution that LINQ to SQL implementations typically uses.

To prevent it you have to invoke `.ToList()`, `FirstOrDefault()` etc within your first method. That makes sure that the query really have been executed against your data source.

Solution:

```
var documents = connection.QueryDocuments(revision).ToList();
foreach(var document in documents) {
    if(fetchedDocuments > fetchQuota) return;
    // [...]
}
```